# Windows 10 default services

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, psutil

Is it possible to filter the windows services using python.

```
import psutil
psutil.process_iter()
```

I could get all running services by using `psutil`
Is there any way to filter windows service from the list of services.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on exactly what you're looking to do, but if you're just looking for a "simple" filter, then you could do something like this:

```
>>> for i in psutil.process_iter(["pid", "name", "exe"]):
...   if i.info["name"] in ["explorer.exe"]:
...     i.info
...
{'name': 'explorer.exe', 'pid': 2124, 'exe': 'C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe'}
```

---

If you'd like to look for services that are has as path containing `windows` then you can do this:

```
for i in psutil.win_service_iter():
  if "windows" in i.binpath().lower():
    print(i.name())
```

This will spam out a lot of info, a slice of which for me is:

```
COMSysApp
CoreMessagingRegistrar
cphs
CryptSvc
CscService
```

Comment: I want to filter all windows default services.

Comment: @VineeshTP I have added more code to search for specifically windows-services. I don't think there is a simple way to search for the _default_ services though.